# Uses of NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll

Tags: nhibernate

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 project i am using Nhibernate for that i referenced two DLLs that is--

1.LinFu.DynamicProxy.dll

2.NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll

I dont know the use of these two DLLs,even if i remove reference of these two DLLs then project builds successfully.
Then what is the use of these DLLs?

Also,in `hibernate-configuration` i have entry like--

```
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
         NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
      </property>
```

what it tells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There was a breaking news in NHibernate `2.1`:

> BREAKING CHANGES from NH2.0.xGA to NH2.1.0
>
> If you want work using lazy loading with LinFu.DynamicProxy now you must deploy NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll

which introduced the possiblity not only use Castle as a proxy generator.

2) NHibernate `3.2` introduced another chang. This distribution itself contains the proxy generator, there is no need to install it `LinFu`. So if you are running the NH 3.2+ you do not need LinFu

If you have version `2.1` - `3.1`: Then (in the runtime) NHibernate will load the proxy generator which you specify in the config:

```
<session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
...
 <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
    NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory
   , NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
</property>
...
```

This library is not needed in a build time (it only implements interfaces). But if you will upgrade to NH 3.2+ you do not have to solve it anymore...

Comment: Is there any proxy genrator in Hibernate.?

Comment: It is built in the NH 3.2+... you do not have to care anymore! ;)

Comment: no no i m asking about Hibernate (without 'N') is there any proxy genrator for HIBERNATE.?

Comment: I am talking about NHiberante. As your question and tag. But Hibernate has proxy genearator as well. NHiberante was firstly ported from it...

Comment: ok,can you help me for [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494970/how-to-configure-proxy-genearator-in-hibernate)